# Display Clear Button when data is entered into input box.And Hide the clear button when input is not focused and no data is in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Code   http://jsbin.com/bebug/7/edit?html,css,js,output  .It show Clear Button if we enter input.But when the input is not focused that clear button should disappear.It should appear only when input is focused and there is value in input box

HTML

```
<h1>Clear icon inside Input field</h1>
<input class="clearable" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter a Search term" />
```

CSS

```
.clearable {
    background: #fff url(data:image/gif;
    base64, R0lGODlhBwAHAIAAAP///5KSkiH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAHAAcAAAIMTICmsGrIXnLxuDMLADs=) no-repeat right -10px center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 4px;
    /* Use the same right padding (18) in jQ! */
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: background 0.4s;
}
.clearable.x {
    background-position: right 5px center;
}
.clearable.onX {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // CLEARABLE INPUT
    function tog(v) {
        return v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    }
    $(document).on('input', '.clearable', function () {
        $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
    }).on('mousemove', '.x', function (e) {
        $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
    }).on('touchstart click', '.onX', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change CSS

```
.clearable.x
```

to

```
.clearable.x:focus
```